# equivalence of properties. Is the restriction in (ii) redundant?

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I have a question about the claim,  which I found in a paper:

Let $\phi:A\to B$ a linear map between $C^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$. The following are equivalent:

1. $\phi(\frac{1}{2}(ab+ba))=\frac{1}{2}(\phi(a)\phi(b)+\phi(b)\phi(a))$ for all $a,b\in A$, and
2. $\phi(a^2)=\phi(a)^2$ for all $a\in A$ such that $0\le a\le 1$.

My question is, why the condition $0\le a\le 1$ in the second property is necessary. In my opinion it is true for all $a\in A$.
Look at this question, [Jordan-homomorphism; equivalent properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320141/jordan-homomorphism-equivalent-properties), the situation is very simliar.

Do you have an idea, why there is the restriction "$0\le a\le 1$" ?.

Comment: If the statement is that the two are equivalent, why do you feel that the restriction states a necessary condition?

Comment: no, the restriction isn't necessary in my opinion. But I'm a little bit worried

Comment: I think this restriction tell us if (ii) hold for $0\leq a\leq 1$, then we get (i).

Comment: yes, but you get (i) too if a is an arbitrary element of A

Comment: So with this  restriction  it is only needed to check (ii) for $0\leq a\leq1$.

Comment: ok. I thanks. I will accept this